# How can I set scale depends from screen ratio?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

in this code, the font size increases in proportion to the screen ratio

```css
/*
@mixin fontSuperSize($number){
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
            font-size: $number * 2vh;
    }
    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
            font-size: $number * 1vw;
    }   
}*/
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2 / 1) {
      div {
        font-size: 8vh; } }
    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 2 / 1) {
      div {
        font-size: 4vw; } }
```

```html
<div>1234567890987654321</div>
```

The length of the child elements is more than 100 vmin in total, and therefore the adjustment comes. I need to reduce the scale of the child elements so that the adjustment does not occur on the square screens.
How can I do the same as for text but for a div. That is what I have now...
[image: 16x9]

[image: 10x10]

How can I make it so that the div does not work out

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="auth"></div>
    <div class="table" ></div>
    <div class="news" ></div>
</div>


<style>
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .auth {
    width: 60vmin;
    height: 60vmin;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    right : 2%;
  }
  .table {
      width: 60vmin;
    height: 20vmin;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 2%;
  }
  .news {
        width: 70vmin;
    height: 20vmin;
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2.5%;
    bottom: 2.5%;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to do. Which one is the expected outcome? Could you try to rephrase the problem in a simple sentence?

Comment: I want to make it so that the elements do not overlap and shrink when the screen size is reduced. When using vmin, the blocks are very small and I would like them to be larger if the length / height allows

Comment: Is news allowed to grow to the left under auth? Can table grow upto news? Have you considered using a CSS grid?